# How can I solve this ActionMailer error with haml templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

I want to use the HAML syntax for my mails. My React app is only an API, so there is not frontend.

- Rails 5.2.1
- ruby 2.5.1
- haml (~> 5.0.4)
- haml-rails (~> 1.0.0)

Curiously, as soon as I rename the views for the mailer from *.html.erb to *.html.haml, I get this error message when trying to send a mail.

```
51: from -e:1:in `<main>'
50: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
49: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
48: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
47: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
46: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `block in load'
45: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
44: from /Users/steven/coding/mge/mge-finpowerment/bin/rails:11:in `<top (required)>'
43: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
42: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
41: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
40: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
39: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
38: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
37: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
36: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
35: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
34: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
33: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
32: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
31: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:64:in `start'
30: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:383:in `start'
29: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:427:in `run'
28: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:427:in `catch'
27: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:428:in `block in run'
26: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:487:in `eval_input'
25: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
24: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
23: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
22: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
21: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
20: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:488:in `block in eval_input'
19: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
18: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:491:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
17: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/context.rb:380:in `evaluate'
16: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/workspace.rb:85:in `evaluate'
15: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/workspace.rb:85:in `eval'
14: from (irb):2:in `irb_binding'
13: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:103:in `deliver_now!'
12: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:17:in `handle_exceptions'
11: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:104:in `block in deliver_now!'
10: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:276:in `deliver!'
 9: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/letter_opener-1.6.0/lib/letter_opener/delivery_method.rb:24:in `deliver!'
 8: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy.rb:29:in `open'
 7: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:79:in `open'
 6: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/application.rb:58:in `run'
 5: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:62:in `run'
 4: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:120:in `wet_run'
 3: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:120:in `fork'
 2: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:123:in 'block in wet_run'
 1: from /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:144:in 'exec_or_raise'
 /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/detect/runner.rb:144:in `exec': No such file or directory - NONE (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Does anybody have a hint where to look at?

Comment: I'm confused, you say you want to use HAML and then you say the error appears when you change your HAML views to ERB. Also, the error does not look related to the views. Try creating the email but don't send it, call `.body` on it instead of `deliver_now!`, it will render the view and you'll know if the error is actually rendering the view or somewhere else.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks for pointing that out. I twisted both. I get the error, when I use the haml file extension. The mail gets rendered propoerly though, when I use `.body`.

Comment: It looks like a letter_opener issue, it's telling launchy to open the email on a browser but it can't find the file to open. I'm not sure what could be the problem (try reconfiguring letter_opener and check if the emails are properly saving on the tmp folder).

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks for the hint. I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need set a BROWSER environment variable in the `~/.bashrc`, for example (using Google Chrome):

```
echo 'export BROWSER=google-chrome' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Or you can run the server with (using Firefox):

```
BROWSER=firefox rails server
```